# What makes Google Chrome Executes user32.dll's SendMessage Commands?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, sendmessage, user32

Google chrome is able to execute the SendMessage Function messages

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool SendMessage(int hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

I wanna have an insight on how or why does it execute them?
and can I create an C# app on my own to execute SendMessage Commands?

Comment: see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Windows apps are driven by messages underneath, so such an API is used whenever necessary. For your C# apps, use PInvoke. Too broad a question, as the more you learn about Windows programming the more you know you know it is a common practice for app developers.

Comment: Well, for the time being everything seems to work just fine! but some C# controls such as the web browser is not responding to these messages. The message I send was a click. why is this happening? Thanks in advance

Comment: Well problem solved, the web browser was displaying flash content and a flash content will have its own handle. you will just need to find it before posting or sending the message